# MYSQL ORDER BY mix ASC and DESC in the same field

Tags: mysql

Need to order the below table by mix of both Descinding and Ascending

I have a table with the filed "Numbers" has values 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 and field "letters" has values, a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j

below is the suggested SQL code

```
(SELECT * FROM table WHERE letters ='e' ORDER BY Numbers DESC, ascend);
```

Hence, I want a result = e,d,f,c,g,b,h,a,i
i.e. If I choose 5, I want the result to start from 5, then desc to 4, then ascend to 6, then desc to 3, then ascend to 7 ..etc

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Hi Strawberry, this is more complex than you think, If I select ORDER BY ASC only the result will be, 5,6,7,8,9,  also, if I select ORDER BY DESC the result will be 5,4,3,2,1. however, I want the result to be 5,4,6,3,7,2,8,1,9, just like first DESC, then ASC and so on

Comment: No. It's exactly as complex as I think.

Comment: You have 2 'I want result' what should your result look like? Examples please including where = a and where = j

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort the table like this:

```
select *
from tablename
order by abs(Numbers - 5), Numbers - 5
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3qCQBWGjZqNt6MZ2rpyVy8/4).
Results:

```
| Numbers | Letters |
| ------- | ------- |
| 5       | e       |
| 4       | d       |
| 6       | f       |
| 3       | c       |
| 7       | g       |
| 2       | b       |
| 8       | h       |
| 1       | a       |
| 9       | i       |
| 10      | j       |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
select *, (numbers - 5) * 2 as seq from t where numbers >= 5
union
select *, (5 - numbers) * 2 - 1 from t where numbers < 5
order by seq
```

Result:

```
  numbers   letters   seq  
  -------   -------   ---
  5         e         0    
  4         d         1    
  6         f         2    
  3         c         3    
  7         g         4    
  2         b         5    
  8         h         6    
  1         a         7    
  9         i         8    
  10        j         10
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2cYK5ZWqeSGQB6NoiUGaJF/0).

Comment: this is good with if there is only if you have 2 fields, I have a database with more than 2 fields, i.e. I have multiple values more than 5 for each number in corresponding filed,.

Comment: $sql_near_by = mysql_query("(SELECT *, (business_postcode - 2165) * 2 AS SEQ FROM business WHERE business_postcode >= 2165  AND business_category ='consultant'  $limit) 

 UNION 
 
 (SELECT *, (2165 - business_postcode) * 2 - 1 FROM business WHERE business_postcode < 2165 AND business_category ='consultant'  $limit)
ORDER BY SEQ
");

Comment: HI The Impaler,  The problem I have multiples of suburbs under each post code, Also, I have multiple of consultants foe each suburb,  your code is only showing 1 consultant and missing other consultants in that suburb and in that postcode.

Comment: Then that's a different question. Please ask again.